# PuPHPet forwarding not working, blocked by iptables

Tags: vagrant, karma-runner, iptables, puphpet

I just added two new ports to my PuPHPet **config.yaml** as follows:

```
vflnp_fajlkhsdkfl:
    host: '9876'
    guest: '9876'
vflnp_akjfhsdasffa:
    host: '3011'
    guest: '3011'
```

And they do show up when turning on the machine

```
Bringing machine 'local' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> local: Checking if box 'puphpet/centos65-x64' is up to date...
==> local: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> local: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    local: Adapter 1: nat
    local: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> local: You are trying to forward to privileged ports (ports <= 1024). Most
==> local: operating systems restrict this to only privileged process (typically
==> local: processes running as an administrative user). This is a warning in ca                                                                                                                                                                                               se
==> local: the port forwarding doesn't work. If any problems occur, please try a
==> local: port higher than 1024.
==> local: Forwarding ports...
    local: 3306 (guest) => 3306 (host) (adapter 1)
    local: 80 (guest) => 80 (host) (adapter 1)
    local: 8000 (guest) => 8000 (host) (adapter 1)
    local: 9876 (guest) => 9876 (host) (adapter 1)
    local: 3011 (guest) => 3011 (host) (adapter 1)
    local: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> local: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> local: Booting VM...
==> local: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    local: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    local: SSH username: vagrant
    local: SSH auth method: private key
```

They're also listed by Virtual Box

[image]

But when trying to establish connection in those new ports, they just get dropped by iptables. I know this because running **iptables -F** instantly resolves the problem until the next reboot.

```
# iptables -L -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           /* 000 accept all icmp */
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           /* 001 accept all to lo interface */
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           /* 002 accept related established rules */ state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           multiport ports 22 /* 100 tcp/22 */
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           multiport ports 3306 /* 100 tcp/3306 */
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           multiport ports 443 /* 100 tcp/443 */
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           multiport ports 80 /* 100 tcp/80 */
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           /* 999 drop all */
```

Why isn't rules for **8000**, **9876**, **3011** being created on **iptables**?

**indexes**: karma; karma-js; port 9876; remote access; karma start;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, it was a [bug that was fixed](https://github.com/puphpet/puphpet/issues/2402#issuecomment-251812735).